# Asus N82J won't boot from DVD

Tags: windows-7, boot, installation, uefi

I have a Asus N82J and I want to reinstall Win7. I have a DVD, which boots on other PCs as expected.

The UEFI is set to boot from DVD, but it wont find any bootable media.

I can not find an option to enable legacy bios boot or CMS.

Comment: What kind of OS it has?

Comment: I’m not sure, what you mean. Win7 is installed on this machine

Comment: I was thinking that you have Windows 8 currently. So, never mind. You could try pressing ESC button when you turn your computer on. That should take you to boot manager.

Comment: I did this already. It doesn’t work. Still can not find any bootable media

Comment: I had similar issue like yours. I also couldn't boot from DVD. The difference is I had Windows 8. So I called Asus and they told me to unplug from outlet and take the battery off and turn it on after 30 seconds. By the way is your boot option turned on from BIOS? I can see on your question "UEFI is set to boot from DVD", but sometimes there is another switch that can enable or disable boot manager.

Comment: Just took out the battery. Nothing changed. Don’t have the option to disable boot manager. This BIOS has really few options

Comment: are you able to see the boot manager when you press ESC?

Comment: after using an external USB drive, I found out, you can not use the USB 3.0 port for boot. As a Mac guy I wasn’t even aware, there are machines with separate 2.0 and 3.0…
anyway… with the external drive at the USB 2.0 port, I could finally install Win7!

Comment: I am glad that worked for you! You should post your answer.

Answer (score 1):

after using an external USB drive, I found out, you can not use the USB 3.0 port for boot. As a Mac guy I wasn’t even aware, there are machines with separate 2.0 and 3.0… anyway… with the external drive at the USB 2.0 port, I could finally install Win7!